# Workflow using semantic release fails to generate version even if it runs with no errors

Tags: github-actions, semantic-release

I have a very simple GitHub Actions workflow which up until 2 weeks ago was working fine but it suddenly stopped generating changelog and new version tags.

Commits are of the type `fix: some message`

And token is valid.

```
name: Release
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  release:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '18'
     
      - name: Semantic Release
        uses: cycjimmy/semantic-release-action@v4
        id: semantic
        with:
          extra_plugins: |
            conventional-changelog-conventionalcommits
            @semantic-release/commit-analyzer
            @semantic-release/release-notes-generator
            @semantic-release/npm
            @semantic-release/git
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

Debug log:

```
##[debug]Evaluating: secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN
##[debug]Evaluating Index:
##[debug]..Evaluating secrets:
##[debug]..=> Object
##[debug]..Evaluating String:
##[debug]..=> 'GITHUB_TOKEN'
##[debug]=> '***'
##[debug]Result: '***'
##[debug]Evaluating: secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN
##[debug]Evaluating Index:
##[debug]..Evaluating secrets:
##[debug]..=> Object
##[debug]..Evaluating String:
##[debug]..=> 'GITHUB_TOKEN'
##[debug]=> '***'
##[debug]Result: '***'
##[debug]Evaluating condition for step: 'Semantic Release'
##[debug]Evaluating: success()
##[debug]Evaluating success:
##[debug]=> true
##[debug]Result: true
##[debug]Starting: Semantic Release
##[debug]Loading inputs
##[debug]Loading env
Run cycjimmy/semantic-release-action@v4

added 370 packages, and audited 619 packages in 6s

95 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

##[debug]Initialization successful
##[debug]action_workspace: /home/runner/work/_actions/cycjimmy/semantic-release-action/v4
##[debug]process.cwd: /home/runner/work/vue-library/vue-library
##[debug]
##[debug]
##[debug]added 3 packages, removed 1 package, and changed 6 packages in 1s
##[debug]
##[debug]98 packages are looking for funding
##[debug]  run `npm fund` for details
##[debug]
##[debug]branches input: 
##[debug]branch input: 
##[debug]semanticMajorVersion: 21
##[debug]dryRun input: 
##[debug]ci input: 
##[debug]extend input: 
##[debug]citagFormat input: 
[1:50:08 PM] [semantic-release] › ℹ  Running semantic-release version 21.1.1
[1:50:09 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "verifyConditions" from "@semantic-release/npm"
[1:50:09 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "verifyConditions" from "@semantic-release/github"
[1:50:09 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "verifyConditions" from "@semantic-release/git"
[1:50:09 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "analyzeCommits" from "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer"
[1:50:09 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "generateNotes" from "@semantic-release/release-notes-generator"
[1:50:09 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "prepare" from "@semantic-release/npm"
[1:50:09 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "prepare" from "@semantic-release/git"
[1:50:09 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "publish" from "@semantic-release/npm"
[1:50:09 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "publish" from "@semantic-release/github"
[1:50:09 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "addChannel" from "@semantic-release/npm"
[1:50:09 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "addChannel" from "@semantic-release/github"
[1:50:09 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "success" from "@semantic-release/github"
[1:50:09 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "fail" from "@semantic-release/github"
[1:50:13 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Run automated release from branch master on repository https://github.com/SkipsoLabs/vue-library.git
[1:50:13 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Allowed to push to the Git repository
[1:50:13 PM] [semantic-release] › ℹ  Start step "verifyConditions" of plugin "@semantic-release/npm"
[1:50:13 PM] [semantic-release] [@semantic-release/npm] › ℹ  Verify authentication for registry https://npm.pkg.github.com
[1:50:13 PM] [semantic-release] [@semantic-release/npm] › ℹ  Wrote NPM_TOKEN to /tmp/b3c5b0f325154fd309dd1b9be96c982c/.npmrc
[1:50:13 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Completed step "verifyConditions" of plugin "@semantic-release/npm"
[1:50:13 PM] [semantic-release] › ℹ  Start step "verifyConditions" of plugin "@semantic-release/github"
[1:50:13 PM] [semantic-release] [@semantic-release/github] › ℹ  Verify GitHub authentication (https://api.github.com)
[1:50:13 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Completed step "verifyConditions" of plugin "@semantic-release/github"
[1:50:13 PM] [semantic-release] › ℹ  Start step "verifyConditions" of plugin "@semantic-release/git"
[1:50:13 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Completed step "verifyConditions" of plugin "@semantic-release/git"
[1:50:13 PM] [semantic-release] › ℹ  Found git tag v0.41.0 associated with version 0.41.0 on branch master
[1:50:13 PM] [semantic-release] › ℹ  Found 13 commits since last release
[1:50:13 PM] [semantic-release] › ℹ  Start step "analyzeCommits" of plugin "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer"
##[debug]Node Action run completed with exit code 0
##[debug]Set output new_release_published = false
##[debug]Finishing: Semantic Release
```

NOTE! if I run `npx semantic-release --no-ci` from my local it works fine and publishes the version.

Comment: I have the same problem in my circleci pipeline. The configuration hasn't changed, tokens are valid but suddenly it doesn't work. Have you found any solution ?

Comment: @raffaellopaletta nothing yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest version of `semantic-release-action` was updated to use `Node 20` for its operations.

I suggest you try updating your `setup-node` action to `node-version: '20'`

If that doesn't solve the issue, it was suggested in this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/cycjimmy/semantic-release-action/issues/168) that you might want to pin the following version in your config: `conventional-changelog-conventionalcommits@6.1.0`

There are a few other solutions suggested in the same GitHub Issue what you might want to look into.

Comment: Specifying the version (conventional-changelog-conventionalcommits@6.1.0) did it! Thank you!